# Submitting theory papers to EECS conferences with hard 8/10 page limit

Tags: computer-science, paper-submission, electrical-engineering, extended-paper

Paraphrasing the 'Call for Papers' for the popular networks conference INFOCOM, submissions on a wide range of research topics, spanning both **theoretical** and systems research are invited. INFOCOM also has a hard 8 page limit on submissions including appendices etc.

For papers on the theoretical side / relying on proofs, the 8 page limit is far too short a span to submit self-contained papers. Is there a general protocol for submitting longer theory papers to such conferences which do not explicitly mention anything about an extended-paper being submittable alongside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to submit an extended version of the paper to [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) containing all the additional material needed (e.g., full proofs), referencing the arXiv paper from the submitted conference paper for further details as necessary.

If that does not sound like a good idea, it might suggest that the paper is better submitted to another venue, or perhaps directly to a journal.

---

**Edit**: Just looking now specifically at INFOCOM requirements, peer review is double-blind, which means publishing on arXiv becomes more complicated (obviously you cannot reference an extended paper where the authors are given). What may perhaps work is to informally publish an extended version of the paper online (in a "neutral" location of course, not giving away the identity/affiliation of the author(s)) and reference that in the submitted version, then if the paper is accepted, consider publishing the arXiV version with author names and reference that from the camera ready version. Admittedly this gets more complex, where you should probably contact the PC chairs of the specific conference to see what it the norm in such cases.

Searching further in [the case of INFOCOM](http://infocom2019.ieee-infocom.org/paper-submission-instructions-main-conference):

> - Papers with the same title and abstract should not be posted on a public website, such as arxiv.org, or transmitted via public mailing lists.
> - We allow the use of an anonymous Microsoft OneDrive link for the reviewers to download an extended version of the submitted manuscript with details of mathematical proofs. Needless to say, the extended version of the submitted manuscript will need to be anonymized, following the guidelines above.   It is the responsibility of the authors to make the OneDrive link (and its content) anonymous, with respect to both the owner of the link and people who visit the link. The reviewers, however, are not obliged to read the extended manuscript when evaluating a submitted paper.

Comment: Actually, I worry that the "short" version of such a paper would be subject to easy rejection for lack of completeness. That no matter about the longer version. If the limit is fixed the referees/reviewers aren't going to like needing to go to a long version to evaluate. I think your second suggestion makes more sense.

Comment: Sometimes this is explicitly forbidden (e.g. NIPS) when the conference has double blind reviewing, as it would reveal the author identities.

Comment: @Buffy, I think this is a common procedure for theoretical conferences (submit a short version referencing a long version with full details). I'm certain that reviewers would take this into account (often review forms ask what material the reviewer actually considered, i.e., did they look at the extended version as well).

Comment: @Thomas, indeed this also happens to be the case for the particular venue mentioned in the question; I extended the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'll guess that if you have a long paper, don't submit it to a venue requiring short papers. Somewhere along the line you will lose. I understand your desire to submit to a top conference, but this might not work well for you in this case. "Think of the referees." :)

Comment: I also assume you've considered and rejected the possibility of submitting a subset of the work that is significant and complete. Not always possible, I realize.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not depends on the paper and the community. Submitting straight to journal, one may lose the opportunity to present the work at that conference, and indeed the prestige of having a paper at that conference. In some communities I know, publishing a conference paper with an extended version and later turning that extended version into a journal paper is very common, and seems a win-win situation.

Comment: Some theoretical computer science conferences allow a paper to have appendices, which go beyond the page limit and contain additional information, usually proofs. They do not, however, require the reviewers to pay any attention to such appendices.